# libcurl download speed too slow

Tags: c++, performance, curl, download, libcurl

I have a case where I'm using libcurl with c++ to download a 240 MB file, but it takes 15 minutes to do so.  I have made sure that my write callback is as fast as possible.  It is just writing into an in-memory buffer that is plenty big-enough for the data.  When I use the curl command to download this same file from the same server, it takes less than a minute.  When I use a browser to download the file, it also takes less than a minute.  Is it possible that I'm using libcurl incorrectly?  Here's a snippet of my code...

```
wxString postFields;
postFields += "package_name=" + packageName;

if( desiredVersion != 0 )
        postFields += wxString::Format( "&package_version=v%d", desiredVersion );

curl_easy_reset( curlHandleEasy );

curl_slist_free_all( headers );
headers = nullptr;

headers = curl_slist_append( headers, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
headers = curl_slist_append( headers, "Accept: application/x-zip-compressed" );

url = "http://" + packageServer + ":7000/package_download";
urlData = url.c_str();

binResponse = new BinaryResponse( packageSize );

curl_easy_setopt( curlHandleEasy, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers );
curl_easy_setopt( curlHandleEasy, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postFieldsData );
curl_easy_setopt( curlHandleEasy, CURLOPT_URL, urlData );
curl_easy_setopt( curlHandleEasy, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &Response::WriteCallback );
curl_easy_setopt( curlHandleEasy, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, binResponse );

curlCode = curl_easy_perform( curlHandleEasy );
```

Is there something wrong with my request setup?  If I change my write callback to be a dummy routine that just claims to have written the data, but just throws it away (to be as fast as possible), my download rate is still super slow.

Is it possible that the bottle neck is some sort of security scanning on the network that I'm being subjected to that the browser and curl command aren't?

Comment: What's the code for your WRITEFUNCTION?  Is it any quicker if you comment those two lines out and let curl do the write just for testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had claimed to have tested with a dummy write function, but I actually hadn't.  When I tested with a dummy write function, the download speed was fast.

So I investigated why my write function was slow and discovered that I was using an in-memory stream class that wasn't initialized with the required buffer size, so it was growing as needed.  The growth of the buffer was probably small, and every time it grew, it probably needed to copy the entire contents of the old buffer into the new one....so, long story short: I'm dumb, and the write stream was slow.

Now I initialize my memory stream to the total size of the file so that it never has to grow.  Ugh!  Problem solved.

Comment: In 99.9% of cases buffers should grow exponentially. That would probably fix the problem.